# VirtualHost configuration overwriten the main domain

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

I configure apache to the main domain in my server and it works just fine if just that domain:

in httpd.conf:

```
Listen maindomain.com:80
DocumentRoot "/home/webserver/maindomain/html"
```

but add a VirtualHost like this :

```
<VirtualHost secondoDomain.com>
DocumentRoot /home/webserver/secondoDomain/html/
ServerName secondoDomain.com
ErrorLog /home/webserver/secondoDomain/logs/error_log
CustomLog /home/webserver/secondoDomain/logs/access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

all the calls to http://maindomain.com are been redirected to secondoDomain.com.

Any of you knows why?

Comment: Hi Helena, your question is a better fit for [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). StackOverflow is geared towards programming questions rather than server software configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a virtual host, you need an entry for the main domain as well - as all hosts become virtual.

For example:

```
Listen *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName maindomain.com
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "/home/webserver/maindomain/html"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName seconddomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/webserver/secondoDomain/html/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure you have a `<Directory "/home/webserver/secondoDomain/html/">` for that second folder as well.